# Don't draw window shadow on transparency

Tags: nswindow

I have a custom, semi-transparent window in my application. I want it to have a shadow around its edges, but not under the semi-transperent portion of the window. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make the window transparent
2. Handle the transparency inside the elements you have inside the NSWindow while keeping the NSWindow transparent
3. Set the NSWindow to have no shadow
4. Apply a custom shadow to the elements while the NSWindow shadow remains none